# Rails приложение. Неизвестная ошибка

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Разбираюсь в приложении написанном 2 года назад не мной.
 при попытке создания новой модели(rails g model payments
) вылезает такая **ошибка**:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:316:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `block in load_dependency'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `load_dependency'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/anton/visteh/vk_stats/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
```

**Как исправить?**

Гуглеж результатов не дал.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring', '~> 1.3.6'
end

# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'vkontakte_api', '~> 1.4'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-vkontakte'
gem 'authority'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'morrisjs-rails'
gem 'raphael-rails'
gem 'resque'

gem 'yandex-money-sdk'
```

Comment: bundle install выполняли - он завершается без ошибок? В продакшене какая версия Ruby используется?

Comment: bundle install выполнял, завершается без ошибок.

Comment: Где можно посмотреть какая версия Ruby используется в продакшене?

Comment: В Gemfile стоят версии гемов, которые требует эта ошибка.

Comment: В папке current сервера выполните ruby -v

Comment: Попробуйте удалить гем mysql2 и установить его по-новой

Comment: Переустановка гема mysql2 изменила ситуацию. Теперь выдает следующее:   There is a version mismatch between the spring client and the server.
You should restart the server and make sure to use the same version.
CLIENT: 1.3.3, SERVER: 1.3.6

Comment: Переустановка гема spring на версию сервера приводит к ошибке, описанной в главном посте.

Comment: на сервер доступа нет(

Comment: 1. spring stop
2. bundle install
3. bundle exec rails g model payments
Если не помогло - гемфайл в студию.

Comment: Что означает первый пункт "1. spring stop"? закомментировать гем?

Comment: Добавил в 1й пост Gemfile

Comment: @ToshiDono, нет. в консоли выполнить. Только правильнее наверное так: `bundle exec spring stop`.

Comment: Пишет:

`Spring is not running`

Answer (score 1):

Удали gem, создай заново и выполни эти команды:

1. `gem install bundler`
2. `bundle install`

Comment: Эти действия выполняются автоматически в `rails new`, вряд ли это что-то изменит.

Comment: выполняются, но чтобы сделать `rails new` надо установить gem, а потом рельсы. У меня такого рода ошибки были когда криво ставил `bundler`

Comment: Судя по гемфайлу, работа идёт уже на шаблоне из `rails new`, так что всё это, как видно, уже установлено. UPD: хотя да, 2 года назад... всякое может быть. Только странно, 2 года назад Rails 4.2 ещё ж вроде не существовало.